# can I transform the values into columns on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python imagine I have this as my dataframe, a list of songs and their groups

| Song Title | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Hello | Pop |
| Night Fever | Rock |
| Dancing | Pop |
| My Star | Metal |

I want to be able to transform all the values under "category" into a new dataframe, so the values are columns, and under each column, it lists the songs. See below for desired outcome...

| Pop | Rock | Metal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | Night Fever | My Star |
| Dancing |  |  |

I'm sure theres a simple code for this in either pyhton or pandas, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is pivot: `df.assign(index=df.groupby("Category").cumcount()).pivot("index","Category","SongTitle")` as mentioned in the duplicate link

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find this earlier but this has work :)